# Php Array transposing

Tags: php

i  have  array name grievance_pending it has values like  "a","b","c","d" are particular section and  x,y,z,w are grievance solving level  i  want to show  the status of grievances  how many are pending at x , y, z and w for all the sections
example: array   values  like a-x,a-y,a-z,a-w, b-x,c-x,c-y,d-w,e-x,e-y,e-w in the same way "a" may have 4 values or 3 values or 2 values or 1 values  i want display
as below

```
          x y z w   total 
      a   0 1 2 0    3
      b   0 0 0 1    1
      c   0 5 0 1    6
```

pls suggest any method to transpose array

Comment: This is really hard to understand. Please format your question.

Comment: Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far.

Comment: Thank you i solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

while($row_count = mysql_fetch_array($qry_count,MYSQL_ASSOC))
         {

```
            if($x=="")
              {
                  if ($j>0)
                  {
                  $j++;
                  }
                 $x=$row_count['unitname'];
                 $unit_name[$j][0]=$x;
                 $unit_name[$j][1]=0;
                 $unit_name[$j][2]=0;
                 $unit_name[$j][3]=0;
                 $unit_name[$j][4]=0;               
                 raised_level($raised_level);            
               }
            else
              {
                      $row_count['unitname'];
                     if($x!=$row_count['unitname'])
                       {
                        $j++;
                             $unit_name[$j][0]=$row_count['unitname'];
                             $unit_name[$j][1]=0;
                             $unit_name[$j][2]=0;
                             $unit_name[$j][3]=0;
                             $unit_name[$j][4]=0;
                            raised_level($raised_level);
                             $x="";

                       }
                     else
                       {
                        raised_level($raised_level);
                       }

                }

    }
```

// funtion raised Level
            function raised_level($raised_level)
                {

```
            switch($raised_level)
                                 {
                                  case "FHQrsBranch":
                                    $fhq_count=$fhq_count+$row_count['total_grievances'];
                                        $unit_name[$j][1]=$fhq_count;
                                        $fhq_count=0;

                                    break;

                                  case "Sector":
                                    $sector_count=$sector_count+$row_count['total_grievances'];
                                        $unit_name[$j][2]=$sector_count;
                                        $sector_count=0;

                                    break;

                                  case "Zone":
                                    $zone_count=$zone_count+$row_count['total_grievances'];
                                        $unit_name[$j][3]=$zone_count;
                                        $zone_count=0;
                                    break;

                                  case "Unit":
                                    $unit_count=$unit_count+$row_count['total_grievances'];
                                        $unit_name[$j][4]=$unit_count;
                                        $unit_count=0;
                                        break;                           
                                 }

            }
```